# Laravel 5 deny route for non auth users

Tags: php, laravel

I have this Laravel 5  app. There are two controllers: Index and Home.
In the index, I have the pages visible for users that haven't logged in yet. When a user logs in, he goes to the home controller.
Of course, I want a visitor not being able to view the routes under home-controller.
So I put a check inside the constructor for Home. But it redirects back to the index and doesn't seem to be the right way at all. 
So having this group of routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/home'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('index', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@logout');
});
```

As you can see, I added.

```
Route::auth();
```

Which I thought should manage to deny access for visitors that haven't logged in. The home is still accessible for users that haven't logged in yet.

What is the way to describe directly inside the route.php that a bunch of routes (inside a group I guess) should first go through the authentication before serving the route?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using this code within your controller?

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `auth` middleware to protect your `home` group:

```
Route::auth();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/home'], function () {
        Route::get('index', 'HomeController@index');
        Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@logout');
    });
});
```

You may have a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#protecting-routes

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple in Laravel only thing you have to use is a single `Middleware`

see this [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#protecting-routes)

EX:

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);
```

this profile show route works only if user logged in.

If you have multiple routes to protect from non-authenticate users then use a route group,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/home', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
    // user need to logged in order to access these routes
    Route::get('/', function()
    {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In kernal.php add 'auth' => 'MyespaceAdmin\Http\Middleware\Authenticate' in $routeMiddleware.
2. Authenticate.php in middleware directory check handle function for below code.

   ```
   if ($this->auth->guest()) {
       if ($request->ajax()) {
           return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
       } else {
           return redirect()->guest('your login page url');
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then use middleware auth in routes or in your controller